# If $H$ is a closed subgroup of a profinte group $G$, then $H$ is the inverse limit of the open subgroups of $G$ containing $H$.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, profinite-groups

> Show that if $H$ is a closed subgroup of a profinte group $G$, then $H$ is the inverse limit of the open subgroups of $G$ containing $H$.

I was able to show that $H$ is profinite. I use a constructive proof, but in my approach I used subgroups $H_{i}$ of $G_{i}$, where $(G_{i},\varphi_{ij})$ is the inverse system with inverse limit $(G,\varphi_{i})$. Probabily this approach does not work.

So I would like some hints to solve the problem. My attempt was write $L = \varprojlim_{i \in I}U_{i}$ where $\{U_{i} \mid i \in I, U \supset H, U\text{ open in }G\}$ and show that $L \subset H$ and $H \subset L$. But I dont know how to proceed. Using this idea, I'm stuck in the first point: what are $\varphi_{ij}: U_{j} \to U_{i}$ that make $(U_{i},\varphi_{ij})$ an inverse system? I dont know if this is the best approach.

PS: I can to write a sketch of my proof for "$H$ is profinite" if necessary.

Comment: The set $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_i \}$ of all open subgroups containing $H$ is partially ordered by inclusion: $U_i \le U_j$ iff $U_j \subset U_i$. This makes $(\mathcal{U}, \le)$ a directed set. For $U_i \le U_j$ we define $\varphi_{ij}: U_{j} \to U_{i}$ to be the inclusion map. The inverse limit of this system is nothing else than $\bigcap_i U_i$.

Comment: @PaulFrost nice! I proved in a previous question that $H = \bigcap_{i} U_{i}$. You can make your comment into an answer. For me, it's a great hint.

Comment: I have done so. If you tell me which question you mean, I shall quote it in my answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost I mean about your hint to take the inclusion maps (it answer my question "what are $\varphi_{ij}$ that make $(U_{i},\varphi_{ij})$ an inverse system?"). That was enough using some results that I had proved before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\mathcal U = \{ U_i \}$ of all open subgroups containing $H$ is partially ordered by inclusion: $U_i \le U_j$ iff $U_j \subset U_i$. This makes $(\mathcal U, \le)$ a directed set. For $U_i \le U_j$ we define $\phi_{ij} : U_j \to U_i$ to be the inclusion map. The inverse limit of this system is nothing else than $\bigcap_i U_i$.